# Converting characters/strings to Datetime objects in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a vector `b` of strings as

```
> b
 [1] "Jan 01 2016 00:26:00" "Jan 01 2016 03:06:00" "Jan 01 2016 22:36:00" "Jan 01 2016 17:46:00"
 [5] "Jan 01 2016 18:06:00" "Jan 01 2016 23:16:00" "Jan 01 2016 03:16:00" "Jan 01 2016 09:46:00"
 [9] "Jan 01 2016 00:06:00" "Jan 01 2016 03:56:00"
```

I want to convert them into Date/Time object. I tried:

```
> as.Date(b, "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
 [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
 [9] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
```

Why do I not get H:M:S? By the way, each element of vector `b` is stripped from string of this type `"Fri Jan 01 00:26:00 UTC 2016"` using `substring`.

A solution to convert directly from string `"Fri Jan 01 00:26:00 UTC 2016"` to a date/time object of the format `"2016-01-01 23:59:00"` would be helpful. I will use this date/time column to order the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using as.POSIXct() instead of as.Date() to account for the time component. Some helpful documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/as.POSIX*).

Comment: @AnnVrgyl Did try `as.POSIXct()` before but it returned NAs.  When I tried with `tz="UTC"`, it worked as I needed.  So I tried `as.POSIXct()`, to address my original problem as: `> as.POSIXct("Fri Jan 01 18:06:00 UTC 2016", tz="UTC", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
`. I get NA. Any suggestions?